# Нужен ли UDP веб-серверу?

Tags: веб-сервер

Так ли необходим открытый UDP порт для веб-сервера? Ни когда ранее таким вопросом не задавался, хочется увидеть хороший ответ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если на данном сервере будут обслуживаться доменные зоны, то нужно открыть UDP порт 53. Этот порт обрабатывает запросы доменных имен.Если Вы будете домены направлять по А записи, без использования свои ns, то данный протокол не нужен.

Answer (score 1):

Нет не нужен. Так же как и козе баян.

Comment: Конечно, не нужен! Если также не нужна на серваке раздача UUCP и DNS!

Answer (score 1):

UDP обычно используется для раздачи DHCP, DNS, VoIP, и прочего потокового вещания. Если ваш сервер ничего из этого этого не делает, то там этот протокол и не нужен!

ЗЫ: Если сервер игровой, то скорее всего - будет нужен! Некоторые игрушки для обмена часто пользуются именно UDP-датаграммами для более быстрой передачи.

Answer (score 0):

В Википедии, в принципе, есть описание разницы между UDP и TCP, вкратце, он не надежен для использования в веб-серверах.